# Can you do a search for votes compared to number of answers?

Tags: support

I've got a bit of a thing about when questions have more answers than votes. For me I think it's a signifier of low voting (maybe just my thing). I'm curious to know if it's something that frequently occurs on the site. Does anyone know if there is a way to show questions that have more answers than votes? I know there is some clever searches than can be done - is that one of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SQL (a query language) you can write a query (and/or adapt an existing query) using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/queries).

I did that: see [Questions with answers and votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/buddhism/query/358293/questions-with-answers-and-votes).

The 'subtraction' column displays the difference between the number of votes and the number of answers (for each question). You can click on the 'subtraction' column title to sort by largest 'subtraction' value.

For example the top three topics (with the largest subtraction values) are:

```
5699 Is our mind faster than light? 12 1 11
5276 Is Buddha a Man or Woman? 9 -2 11
5398 Can one practice meditation to gain knowledge about the universe? 10 2 8
```

It looks like about a third of the topics have a value of at least 1.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for that. I just had the feeling that voting had dropped recently. I always think that if someone has answered a question there is probably merit in that question so why not upvote. That said your query does point out some very confused questions so that's not always the case by any means. I can write SQL so i think i'll have alook at this when i get a moment. Very interesting. Thanks